# How can I sort by last word in the node title field?

Tags: 7, views

In one of my content type, we are storing names in the Title field. For example, title is "John Smith". Due to the recent requirement change we now need to sort results by last name.

But since the name is stored in Title how can I sort by last name in the view? Is there a way I can create a field which automatically gets the last word in the title? Or may be some other way that I am missing out?

Comment: please show an example of a Title. depending on the layout, you could do a one time bulk update, copying the values into separate fields. If there aren't that many, you could also do it manually

Comment: Yeah, +1 for creating another (hidden) textfield to store the last name on every entity insert/update. I'd recommend doing this from a small custom module implementing [`hook_node_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) or some similar hook. There you split up the title and store the last word in the new last name field. You could also use [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) for doing this. Then resave all existing nodes to have the logic kick in.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not best solution, but it should work:

Try [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php). With this module you should be able to create sorting in view which will take only last word of given string (content of your title field) with PHP code (something like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612872/get-the-last-word-of-a-string)).

> This module allows the admin account (user 1) to add fields, filters and sorts to views which use PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption on the Last Name field. If you got the first and last names from a user which is related to the nodes being listed in the view, then you can add a **View: Relationship** to the User entity maybe then order the query by the related user's last name.